# Validate2 function is not able to pull up form inputs

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
function validate()
{
var email=document.getElementById("email").value;
var pass=document.getElementById("pass").value;
if(pass==" " || email==" ")
{
alert("Please fill all the requred field");}
else if(pass.length <3)
{alert("password is too short");}
else{alert(email);
alert(pass);
alert("form submission successful");}
}
/*PROBLEM IS IN THE BELOW CODE */
/* VALIDATE2 FUNCTION IS UNABLE TO PULL UP ANY FORM INPUTS */
function validate2()
{
  var R_name=document.getElementById("R_name").value;
var R_email=document.getElementById("R_email").value;
var R_number=document.getElementById("R_number").value;
var R_pass=document.getElementById("R_pass").value;

if(R_name =="" ||R_email==""||R_number==""||R_pass=="")
{alert("please fill the form");}
else{
alert(R_name);
alert(R_email);
alert(R_number);
alert(R_pass);
alert("registered successfully");
}}
```

```css
body{font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif; color:#666; font-size:14px; color:#333}
li,ul,body,input{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none}
#login-form{width:350px; background:#FFF; margin:0 auto; margin-top:70px; background:#f8f8f8; overflow:hidden; border-radius:7px}
.form-header{display:table; clear:both}
.form-header label{display:block; cursor:pointer; z-index:999}
.form-header li{margin:0; line-height:60px; width:175px; text-align:center; background:#eee; font-size:18px; float:left; transition:all 600ms ease}

/*sectiop*/
.section-out{width:700px; float:left; transition:all 600ms ease}
.section-out:after{content:''; clear:both; display:table}
.section-out section{width:350px; float:left}

.login{padding:20px}
.ul-list{clear:both; display:table; width:100%}
.ul-list:after{content:''; clear:both; display:table}
.ul-list li{ margin:0 auto; margin-bottom:12px}
.input{background:#fff; transition:all 800ms; width:247px; border-radius:3px 0 0 3px; font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif; border:solid 1px #ccc; border-right:none; outline:none; color:#999; height:40px; line-height:40px; display:inline-block; padding-left:10px; font-size:16px}
.input,.login span.icon{vertical-align:top}
.login span.icon{width:50px; transition:all 800ms; text-align:center; color:#999; height:40px; border-radius:0 3px 3px 0; background:#e8e8e8; height:40px; line-height:40px; display:inline-block; border:solid 1px #ccc; border-left:none; font-size:16px}
.input:focus:invalid{border-color:red}
.input:focus:invalid+.icon{border-color:red}
.input:focus:valid{border-color:green}
.input:focus:valid+.icon{border-color:green}
#check,#check1{top:1px; position:relative}
.btn{border:none; outline:none; background:#0099CC; border-bottom:solid 4px #006699; font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif; margin:0 auto; display:block; height:40px; width:100%; padding:0 10px; border-radius:3px; font-size:16px; color:#FFF}

.social-login{padding:15px 20px; background:#f1f1f1; border-top:solid 2px #e8e8e8; text-align:right}
.social-login a{display:inline-block; height:35px; text-align:center; line-height:35px; width:35px; margin:0 3px; text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF}
.form a i.fa{line-height:35px}
.fb{background:#305891} .tw{background:#2ca8d2} .gp{background:#ce4d39} .in{background:#006699}
.remember{width:50%; display:inline-block; clear:both; font-size:14px}
.remember:nth-child(2){text-align:right}
.remember a{text-decoration:none; color:#666}

.hide{display:none}

/*swich form*/
#signup:checked~.section-out{margin-left:-350px}
#login:checked~.section-out{margin-left:0px}
#login:checked~div .form-header li:nth-child(1),#signup:checked~div .form-header li:nth-child(2){background:#e8e8e8}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="login-form">

<input type="radio" checked id="login" name="switch" class="hide">
<input type="radio" id="signup" name="switch" class="hide">

<div>
<ul class="form-header">
<li><label for="login"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> LOGIN<label for="login"/></label></li>
<li><label for="signup"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i> REGISTER</label></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="section-out">
<section class="login-section">
<div class="login">
<form action="">
<ul class="ul-list">
<li><input type="email" required class="input" placeholder="Your Email" id="email"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="password" required class="input" placeholder="Password" id="pass"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span></li>
<li><span class="remember"><input type="checkbox" id="check"> <label for="check">Remember Me</label></span><span class="remember"><a href="">Forget Password</a></span></li>
<li><input type="submit" value="SIGN IN" class="btn" onclick="validate()"></li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>

<div class="social-login">Or sign in with &nbsp;
<a href="" class="fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
<a href="" class="tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
<a href="" class="gp"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
<a href="" class="in"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
</div>
</section>

<section class="signup-section">
<div class="login">
<form action="">
<ul class="ul-list">
<li><input type="name" required class="input" placeholder="Your Name" id="R_name"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="number" required class="input" placeholder="Your Number" id="R_number"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="email" required class="input" placeholder="Your Email" id=R_email/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="password" required class="input" placeholder="Password" id="R_pass"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="check1"> <label for="check1">I accept terms and conditions</label></li>
<li><input type="submit" value="SIGN UP" class="btn" onclick="validate2()"></li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>

<div class="social-login">Or sign up with &nbsp;
<a href="" class="fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
<a href="" class="tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
<a href="" class="gp"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
<a href="" class="in"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
</div>
</section>
</div>

</div>

</body>
```

Please advise me how to get the user input of registration form and get it validated in javascript.
Please note that the validation 1 function is able to pull up the user form inputs from login section but not the validation2 function from the registration section.
I have designed the form in such a way the sections are switchable inside div container using a radio button. 
The login section form will be displayed by default if the user clicks on the signup radio button then the signup section form of the div container will switch(becomes visible) and the login section of the form goes hidden.

Comment: [When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide the minimal code people can use to reproduce the problem. Click this comment to find out how to provide what we need to help you.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Keyword is *minimal*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have just went through your code. Your JS code has no error! you have just done a small mistake on your form html code. You have forgotten to put a double quote to your attribute value for "R_email". That's it. I have just corrected the code for you and here it is.

```js
function validate()
{
var email=document.getElementById("email").value;
var pass=document.getElementById("pass").value;
if(pass==" " || email==" ")
{
alert("Please fill all the requred field");}
else if(pass.length <3)
{alert("password is too short");}
else{alert(email);
alert(pass);
alert("form submission successful");}
}
/*PROBLEM IS IN THE BELOW CODE */
/* VALIDATE2 FUNCTION IS UNABLE TO PULL UP ANY FORM INPUTS */
function validate2()
{
  var R_name=document.getElementById("R_name").value;
var R_email=document.getElementById("R_email").value;
var R_number=document.getElementById("R_number").value;
var R_pass=document.getElementById("R_pass").value;

if(R_name =="" ||R_email==""||R_number==""||R_pass=="")
{alert("please fill the form");}
else{
alert(R_name);
alert(R_email);
alert(R_number);
alert(R_pass);
alert("registered successfully");
}}
```

```css
body{font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif; color:#666; font-size:14px; color:#333}
li,ul,body,input{margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none}
#login-form{width:350px; background:#FFF; margin:0 auto; margin-top:70px; background:#f8f8f8; overflow:hidden; border-radius:7px}
.form-header{display:table; clear:both}
.form-header label{display:block; cursor:pointer; z-index:999}
.form-header li{margin:0; line-height:60px; width:175px; text-align:center; background:#eee; font-size:18px; float:left; transition:all 600ms ease}

/*sectiop*/
.section-out{width:700px; float:left; transition:all 600ms ease}
.section-out:after{content:''; clear:both; display:table}
.section-out section{width:350px; float:left}

.login{padding:20px}
.ul-list{clear:both; display:table; width:100%}
.ul-list:after{content:''; clear:both; display:table}
.ul-list li{ margin:0 auto; margin-bottom:12px}
.input{background:#fff; transition:all 800ms; width:247px; border-radius:3px 0 0 3px; font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif; border:solid 1px #ccc; border-right:none; outline:none; color:#999; height:40px; line-height:40px; display:inline-block; padding-left:10px; font-size:16px}
.input,.login span.icon{vertical-align:top}
.login span.icon{width:50px; transition:all 800ms; text-align:center; color:#999; height:40px; border-radius:0 3px 3px 0; background:#e8e8e8; height:40px; line-height:40px; display:inline-block; border:solid 1px #ccc; border-left:none; font-size:16px}
.input:focus:invalid{border-color:red}
.input:focus:invalid+.icon{border-color:red}
.input:focus:valid{border-color:green}
.input:focus:valid+.icon{border-color:green}
#check,#check1{top:1px; position:relative}
.btn{border:none; outline:none; background:#0099CC; border-bottom:solid 4px #006699; font-family: 'Ropa Sans', sans-serif; margin:0 auto; display:block; height:40px; width:100%; padding:0 10px; border-radius:3px; font-size:16px; color:#FFF}

.social-login{padding:15px 20px; background:#f1f1f1; border-top:solid 2px #e8e8e8; text-align:right}
.social-login a{display:inline-block; height:35px; text-align:center; line-height:35px; width:35px; margin:0 3px; text-decoration:none; color:#FFFFFF}
.form a i.fa{line-height:35px}
.fb{background:#305891} .tw{background:#2ca8d2} .gp{background:#ce4d39} .in{background:#006699}
.remember{width:50%; display:inline-block; clear:both; font-size:14px}
.remember:nth-child(2){text-align:right}
.remember a{text-decoration:none; color:#666}

.hide{display:none}

/*swich form*/
#signup:checked~.section-out{margin-left:-350px}
#login:checked~.section-out{margin-left:0px}
#login:checked~div .form-header li:nth-child(1),#signup:checked~div .form-header li:nth-child(2){background:#e8e8e8}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="login-form">

<input type="radio" checked id="login" name="switch" class="hide">
<input type="radio" id="signup" name="switch" class="hide">

<div>
<ul class="form-header">
<li><label for="login"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> LOGIN<label for="login"/></label></li>
<li><label for="signup"><i class="fa fa-credit-card"></i> REGISTER</label></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="section-out">
<section class="login-section">
<div class="login">
<form action="">
<ul class="ul-list">
<li><input type="email" required class="input" placeholder="Your Email" id="email"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="password" required class="input" placeholder="Password" id="pass"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span></li>
<li><span class="remember"><input type="checkbox" id="check"> <label for="check">Remember Me</label></span><span class="remember"><a href="">Forget Password</a></span></li>
<li><input type="submit" value="SIGN IN" class="btn" onclick="validate()"></li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>

<div class="social-login">Or sign in with &nbsp;
<a href="" class="fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
<a href="" class="tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
<a href="" class="gp"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
<a href="" class="in"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
</div>
</section>

<section class="signup-section">
<div class="login">
<form action="">
<ul class="ul-list">
<li><input type="name" required class="input" placeholder="Your Name" id="R_name"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="number" required class="input" placeholder="Your Number" id="R_number"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="email" required class="input" placeholder="Your Email" id="R_email"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="password" required class="input" placeholder="Password" id="R_pass"/><span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span></li>
<li><input type="checkbox" id="check1"> <label for="check1">I accept terms and conditions</label></li>
<li><input type="submit" value="SIGN UP" class="btn" onclick="validate2()"></li>
</ul>
</form>
</div>

<div class="social-login">Or sign up with &nbsp;
<a href="" class="fb"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
<a href="" class="tw"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
<a href="" class="gp"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
<a href="" class="in"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a>
</div>
</section>
</div>

</div>

</body>
```

Comment: This can be condensed down to just the lines needed to fix. Please do so, in order to have a more clear answer. Need help? read [answer].